# How can I change my tabset to pills in Flexdashboard?

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I am trying to customize a flexdashboard (non-Shiny). I have several graphs that will be tabset on the primary dashboard page.

I can get the tabset to work successfully, but beyond that, I am unable to style the tabs in any way. See below for the standard tabset format I currently have. This is the default format.

[image: See below for the standard tabset format I currently have.]

And here is the code corresponding to the above output:

```
---
title: "My Title"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    theme: cerulean
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: fill
---
```

{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)

```
## Row {.tabset}

### Requests

### Transactions 

### Purchases
```

(The rsetup line of code and library(flexdashboard) line of code are surrounded by three apostrophes, but I am not sure of how to format this.

Each tab contains nothing at the moment as I haven't filled with content yet.

I want do several things to customize these tabsets. First, I want to change these to pills. However, when I change the above from:
`## Row {.tabset}`
to
`## Row {.tabset .tabset-pills}`
I get the same output as above. The tabs are not pills. Nothing changes. Similarly, nothing changes when I input `## Row {.tabset .tabset-fade}`. This tells me that the issue is not limited to pills and may be more of an overarching issue.

This is my first problem-- what am I doing incorrectly? I searched online and found that maybe it could be tied to the package versions you are using if they're old, but I have pretty recent versions of everything:
`sessionInfo()` returns:

````
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.6.1      rsconnect_0.8.15    htmltools_0.4.0     tools_3.6.1         flexdashboard_0.5.2 yaml_2.2.0          Rcpp_1.0.2         
 [8] rmarkdown_2.4.2     knitr_1.26          jsonlite_1.6        xfun_0.11           digest_0.6.22       rlang_0.4.4         evaluate_0.14  ```
````

Depending on the answer to this issue, I am further trying to customize the color of an active tab. And all I am able to do is color the entire background row. I wonder if this has something to do with the tab-pills issue I am having.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**Edit:**
I am now able to edit the tabsets to change colors and fonts using my CSS file with the following code:

```
 <style>
.nav-tabs-custom .nav-tabs li.active a {
  color: white !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #1036b3 !important;
}

.nav-tabs-custom .nav-tabs li:not(.active) a {
  color: #f0f0ff;
  background-color: #0a0a54;
}
.nav-tabs-custom > .nav-tabs > li.active a {
    background-color: #1036b3;
    border-top-color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    }

/* To set color on hover */
.nav-tabs-custom .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover {
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #124dc4;
}

/* To set color on hover attempt not active */
.nav-tabs-custom > .nav-tabs > li:not(.active) > a:hover {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
  background-color: #1a1a8a;
}
</style>
```

And here is the output:

[image: Tabsets stylized with colors and fonts]

It's beautiful and dynamically colored.

However, changing tabs to pill shapes still doesn't work. Still looking for help on this-- maybe non-Shiny dashboard can't handle pills? I don't know...Could someone advise me on how to integrate pills into my CSS file if I can't do it simply with the attribute 'tabset-pills' in my R script?

Thanks in advance!